# has anyone actually used sapphire framework from silverstripe?

Tags: php, orm, frameworks

I was looking for a good lightweight framework for php development, I saw symfony, cake, and CI, and found

> sapphire

from silverstripe and I was wondering if anyone has actually used it or if it is just a scam for using silverstripe.

Your comments are very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My two cents: I've occasionally used Silverstripe, and although I'm a fan of it (finally a CMS that's suitable *also* for programmers!), I wouldn't use the framework alone. There are better alternatives out there in terms of the community behind them, the number of useful features and the quality.

Answer (score -1):

I use ci framework with osmek, a cloud cms with an api.  It is a developers dream. Osmek is the perfect cms for developers and my clients love it's intuitive interface.